# Epson PLQ-30M (Matrix) using Olivetti emulation Mode won't print text

Tags: c#, printing, epson

I'm trying to make a C# program to print to an Epson  PLQ-30M using serial (it has to be serial, sorry) and ESC commands with some reporting, but without success.

Well, first I did use EPSON Mode (Emulation) and ESC codes and all worked good, but the problem is... it won't report problems from printer (besides a response of 10 or 13 (generic error and "ready"), and I need some reporting like "has paper", "cover opened", "end of printing", etc...
    that leads me to change to Olivetti mode which has all this responses I needed and works really well using ESC PR2 codes.

The main problem now is: I can't print any text. Any idea why?

Sending ASCII text and LF Command won't print anything.

Another test I did was to switch to USB and make a simple notepad print, don't print anything only when I'm using Olivetti emulation, other emulations print okay. Any clues?

```
serialport1 = new SerialPort("COM4", 9600, Parity.Even, 8, StopBits.One);
serialport1.Encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(28605);  //iso-8859-15  Latin 9 (ISO) 
serialport1.DtrEnable = true;
serialport1.RtsEnable = true;
serialport1.Open();
SendEscapeCharacter("" + (char)27 + (char)48); // 1B 30(HEX)  (INIT PRINTER)
SendEscapeCharacter("" + (char)27 + (char)46); // 1B 2E(Automatic operation mode)
SendEscapeCharacter("" + (char)27 + (char)81 + (char)50 + (char)50 + (char)50 + (char)27 + (char)90); // (Line unit page length setting)

serialport1.Write("testing");  // tRYING TO Print "Testing"
SendEscapeCharacter("" + (char)27 + (char)10); //LF
// READY LED IS BLINKING(orange) AND NO PRINTING!
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. Please include your code and what you have tried so far

Comment: Thank you, here it is what im trying to do using Epson Printer on Olivetti emulation (Serie port)